# Vue trigger request to fetch data from API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm fresh in Vue so this question can be dumb. I want to display data in Vue from my backend Rails API. The data should shows up each time a user enters the site. To do so I'm calling GET endpoint which is located below:

`imports.js`

```
const fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest = (self) => {
  const jwtToken = self.$store.state.idToken;

  return axios
    .get(`/api/v1/imports/products/sync_result`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      self.unsyncedProducts = response.data['products']
    })
};

export {
  fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest
};
```

Expected JSON response from this GET will be:

```
{:products=>
  [{:id=>"611ea9a7392ab50013cf4713", :name=>"2-Tone Hoodie", :code=>"SS22CH013", :result=>nil, :last_sync_at=>nil},
   {:id=>"60ec84062f25d400150b351c", :name=>"5-Pocket Denim", :code=>"SS22WP014", :result=>nil, :last_sync_at=>nil},
   {:id=>"61966dc83e81dd001731ccd7", :name=>"Zip Shirt Jacket", :code=>"FW22WT001", :result=>nil, :last_sync_at=>nil},
   {:id=>"61d5cab6b41408001b0e9376", :name=>"Yankees Satin Varsity Jacket", :code=>"FW22WJ021", :result=>nil, :last_sync_at=>nil}]}
```

Inside my Vue file I've got:

`sync_products.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <h4>Synchronize products</h4>
        <div v-for="product in fetchedProductSyncStatus" :key="product" class="status">
          {{product}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import {
  fetchUnsyncedProductsRequest,
} from '../../api/imports'

export default {
    name: 'BackboneSyncProducts',
    data(){
        return{
          fetchedProductSyncStatus: []
        }
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Looks like request is not sent because nothing shows up and I don't see it in Network tab. What determines the sending of this request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hook the fetchUnsyncedProductsRequest function to Vue's lifecycles, like created or mounted. See: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html

I would also change the function to just return the data.

```
const fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest = (token) => {    
  return axios
    .get(`/api/v1/imports/products/sync_result`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.data['products']
    })
};

export {
  fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest
};
```

Then add the created hook and add the response to fetchedProductSyncStatus

```
export default {
    name: 'BackboneSyncProducts',
    data() {
        return{
          fetchedProductSyncStatus: []
        }
    },
    created () {
      const jwtToken = this.$store.state.idToken;
      fetchUnsyncedProductsRequest(jwtToken).then(data => {
        this.fetchedProductSyncStatus = data
      })
    }
}
```

Edit: Fixed the self reference error you commented about. On that note it is bad practice to store token in the client like a store

Comment: Nothing changed - still don't see any request to that endpoint but received error inside Console: `[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$store')"`

Comment: Sorry forgot the self reference, I've updated the code example.